# How to declare paths in PHP to allow easy app move to not rooted folder?

Tags: php, apache, directory

I have wamp setup on my windows box. Generally, when I bring a site down from the web, I create a folder inside my www folder for the site name. ex: c:\wamp\www\mysite. Once I have the folder, I copy down all the live files. The issue is that all the paths are then broken because my local folder isn't rooted.

What is the best way to setup paths so that if the site moves to a folder that isn't rooted, it will work easily?

Comment: unless you're changing all the path logic in the PHP code for a site, you'll be needing to find an apache solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a file (usually called something like `config.php`) to keep track of the root folder. My definitions (constants) look like this:

```
define('BASE_DIR','/wherever/whenever/');
define('LIB_DIR', BASE_DIR . 'lib/');
```

And then when you need to include a file

```
include LIB_DIR . 'aFile.php';
```

This would be something you do on a new site or if you have time to refactor your current site.

Comment: Then don't you have to include the config file in every php file? Or is there a way to not have to do this?

Comment: @Frankie it will depend on how your site is setup. If you dynamically load pages into index.php you would need to include the config only once at the top of index.php. If users are redirected to separate pages, then config.php would need to be included on everyone of those.

Answer (score 2):

Create an include file, that has constants setup based upon whatever the root directory is... then in your code, use the constants you created to include files.

Also note, that when you are using directory "slashes", always use the build in constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of hard coding it, this will allow you to go from WIndows to Linux seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

We use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to determine where we are in the filesystem and then simply append the folder name of our project to that. This works perfectly for us. You should always use a configuration.php where you define basic paths and URL's that may change when moving the project from one server/folder to another.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Use `<base href=""/>` [tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Option 2. Use a config file, like @MattCan suggests

Option 3. Use a server environment variable, like @Bjorn suggests

Option 4. Create a virtual host on your apache, than you can create a domain who appoint exactly where are your app folder. [Apache Doc here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)